# The postal address showing on google search results is incorrect

Tags: google-search, address

I have been asked to be the webmaster of a website. When I type in the name of the company on Google, the address that comes up on the Google search results page is not the correct address.

The website has a Contact US page and that page has the correct address. Where does Google pick up the address from that it displays on the search results page?

Comment: Are you refering to *postal address* or *URL address* ? Maybe you could provide a screenshot of the search result page in question to clarify what's *wrong* ?

Comment: It sounds like postal address to me, I edited that into the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postal address that Google shows for a business in the search results comes from the listing for that business that Google shows on its maps.

To correct that address, claim your business listing in [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/).  Here are [Google's instructions for claiming and verifying](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778?hl=en) your business.   Their [help document for editing your listing](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3039617?hl=en) has instructions for changing the address:

> Enter the complete and exact address for your business location. Read our [address entry guidelines](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2853879) for more recommendations.
>
> Note that changing your address in between the postcard request and verification code entry stages of verification will cause the verification process to reset.

You can also [report a problem](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?hl=en) to Google through maps and hope they check it out and fix it soon.  I don't believe that reporting problems is usually very effective compared to claiming the business listing though.

Comment: Um thanks, but one question. DO I need any login/password from the business owner? This is the business showing wrong address :https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=perri+fine+furniture

Comment: If the business owner has already claimed the business there it would be easiest to use that account to make changes.   You can claim the business for the first time, or with another account, but you have to go through the verification process.

Comment: The very fact it is showing up on google...does it mean they have claimed the business? Do  I ask them if they used a google id?

Comment: They may or may not have claimed the business.  Google imports data from other sources such as yellow pages for inclusion on maps.  If you can't claim the listing, you can always report the problem to Google (I put info into the answer about that.)   Google has had a big problem with vandalism on maps recently.  In some cases business addresses have been changed inappropriately.   They are actually shutting down access to their MapMaker project tomorrow.   Edits and suggestions form users currently have a huge backlog for them to review.